# Create an ORACLE data dictionary of tables with more than 2 indexes

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble trying to figure out in an ORACLE data dictionary whether a table has more than 2 indexes.

Comment: Have you done your research? Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) on how to properly ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by looking at a dictionary table such as [ALL_INDEXES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1096.htm#i1578369) and trying something like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM USER_INDEXES
  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

I haven't tried the code, or read the doc in detail to see if there may be cases where things show up twice, but it should put you on the track.